# how to save user's inputs without backeneds

Tags: django, view

I am just learning Django and web development in general and I was wondering if what I want to do is possible. I would like to write a Django quiz that saves the answers a user inputs without needing a backend. Is this possible?If it is not possible what is the simplest and easiest way I can do this. My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Exam Questions{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    {% if all_questions %}
        <form action="{% url 'save_answer' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for question in all_questions %}
            <h3>{{question.text }}</h3>
            <input type="hidden" name="exam_id" value="{{ question.exam.id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="{{ question.id }}">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{question.answer_set.all}}" name="answers">
        {% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
            <p><input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.text }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
{% else %}
    <h2>No questions available</h2>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Now  I would like to know how to save user answers without backends

Comment: Without a backend *what*? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you can save it in your backend ([django forms doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/)), or save it with javascript in a [client browser cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Answer (score 0):

First, make a litle change with your template to make radio choices work

```
<p><input type="radio" name="answer_{{ question.id }}" value="{{ answer.id }}">{{ answer.option }}</p>
```

Then, here is the code to store answers to session:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post = request.POST
    question_ids = post.getlist('question_id')
    results = dict()
    for id in question_ids:
        answer = post.get('answer_%s' % id)
        results[id] = answer
    # Save to session or do whatever you want.
    request.session['results'] = results
    # Response to review
    return JsonResponse(results)
```